# Spring JSON View

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring MVC and REST.
I am trying to return a JSON response.

So far I have modified a simple Hello World example found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/)

In my Controller, I have this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {

  @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody Movie getMovie(@PathVariable int id) {
    return Movie.getMovie(id);
  }

}
```

The `Movie` class just contains a static collection of Movie instances with id, title and year. Nothing fancy going on there.

My context XML looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
... namespace declarations truncated>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.controller" />

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
  </bean>
```

In the above XML, I declare a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` to always return JSON, and ignore the Accept header and path extension.

I have `jackson-core-lgpl-1.9.13.jar` in my deployed `WEB-INF/lib` so Spring can convert my Movie class to JSON.

However, when I request `http://localhost:8080/myapp/movie/1` I get a HTTP 406 response.

Comment: Please post your server stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson core isn't enough, you need the Jackson mapper. Here's the maven snippet to get the current version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes - I since found out I had the wrong dependency in my Maven POM. That does the trick.